# Value returned and pushed into array but not available outside return

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an Angular service that returns a value. I push that value into an array and console.log shows the value was indeed pushed. But outside this callback the array does not show the pushed value. How can I save this array with the pushed values?

```
$scope.setAddons = function() {
var addons = new Array();
var arr = filterFilter($scope.addons, {checked: true});
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {          
        element = arr[i].addoncode;
        addons.push(element);
        console.log(addons); // ["A6004"] great!
    }           
    for (var x = 0; x < addons.length; x++) {                   
        var dep = '';
        myService.addon_dependencies(addons[x]).then(function(dependency) {
        dep = dependency[0].addon_depend;
        console.log(dep); // A6002
            if(dep != null){
                addons.push(dep);
                console.log(addons); // ["A6004", "A6002"] great!
            }
        });
    }
    myService.addItem('addons', addons); //saving ["A6004"] instead of ["A6004", "A6002"]
    console.log(addons); // ["A6004"] just shoot me!
    location.path("/rates");
}
```

Comment: again. async issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [$q.all](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) to ***synchronously*** execute ***all*** service calls like this:

(Sorry I can't test your code, but you should be able to debug by yourself. Hope it can shed some light on.)

```
$scope.setAddons = function () {
    var addons = new Array();
    var arr = filterFilter($scope.addons, {
        checked: true
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        element = arr[i].addoncode;
        addons.push(element);
        console.log(addons); // ["A6004"] great!
    }

    var queries = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < addons.length; x++) {
        queries.push(myService.addon_dependencies(addons[x]));
    }

    $q.all(queries).then(function (data) {
        for (var x = 0; x < addons.length; x++) {
            var dep = dependency[x].addon_depend;
            console.log(dep); // A6002
            if (dep != null) {
                addons.push(dep);
                console.log(addons); // ["A6004", "A6002"] great!
            }
        }

        myService.addItem('addons', addons); //saving ["A6004"] instead of ["A6004", "A6002"]
        console.log(addons); // ["A6004"] just shoot me!
        location.path("/rates");
    });
}
```

Comment: you should add `$q` to your controller like this `function ctrl($scope, $q)`

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing to `addons` from within a deferred function.

When you log `addons` at the end, you haven't pushed from within your `addon_dependencies().then` function yet.

Your function should look like @sza 's code!

Comment: 'location.path("/rates");' will be called when the call is processed. Doesn't work.

Comment: @sza Which is why I say 'not sure about this one' - If you'd like to be more constructive, I can fix the answer...

Comment: And myService.addItem('addons', addons); will be called N time.

Comment: @sza :D - absolutely right!  I shouldn't have tried to fix angularjs code (not in my wheelhouse).  Think I'll just remove the code part and let the original comment stand.